# sudo: unable to resolve host dhcppc1

Tags: linux, ubuntu, sudo

I get following error whenever i do something like:

```
sudo apt-get install sddm
sudo: unable to resolve host dhcppc1
```

It happened when i upgrade from 14.04 to 16.04.

---

`/etc/hosts`

```
127.0.0.1       localhost.localdomain localhost
127.0.1.1       mlibre-ThinkPad-E555
# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

## Update

I have another problem. whenever i reboot system, this problem happen again.

`/etc/hostname`

```
localhost
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your computer's name (`hostname`) is set to `dhcppc1`, but `dhcppc1` is not in `/etc/hosts` and it cannot be resolved by DNS. The way your `/etc/hosts` looks your computer's name should be `mlibre-ThinkPad-E555`. You must resolve this mismatch.

Comment: fixed by: sudo hostname localhost. i have another problem. question updated.

Comment: Well you did set your hostname to `localhost`. So naturally `/etc/hostname` contains `localhost`.

Comment: yeh. but seems, something change hostname in startup.

Comment: It seems that your DHCP server is setting a hostname. Look at [a similar case](https://support.cumulusnetworks.com/hc/en-us/articles/218289767-Hostname-Configured-in-etc-hostname-Is-Superseded-by-the-DHCP-hostname-Option-).

Comment: Yeh. tnx. fixed by changing: `sudo nano /etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf`.
remove `host-name` form request line.

Answer (score 0):

First of all try rebooting your system. If the problem persists then try these-

**Sol-1**
Go to system-settings-> system-details. 
And there in the overview panel, rename your device to the same device name as mentioned in the /etc/hosts.

This method will change the device name in the etc/hostname without asking you for the admin password.

**Sol-2**
Type the following in the terminal

```
sudo gedit ~/etc/hosts
```

(Although the error will appear here but the terminal will accept your password). There modify the device name to the same name as in etc/hostname file.

This should resolve the mismatch in the hosts and hostname file.